# Why is 'U+' used to designate a Unicode code point?

Tags: unicode, codepoint

Why do Unicode code points appear as **`U+`**`<codepoint>`?

For example, `U+2202` represents the character **∂**.

Why not `U-` (dash or hyphen character) or anything else?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The characters “U+” are an ASCIIfied version of the MULTISET UNION “⊎” U+228E character (the U-like union symbol with a plus sign inside it), which was meant to symbolize Unicode as the union of character sets. See [Kenneth Whistler’s explanation in the Unicode mailing list](http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2005-m11/0060.html).

Answer (score 17):

The Unicode Standard needs some notation for talking about code points and character names. It adopted the convention of "U+" followed by four or more hexadecimal digits at least as far back as [*The Unicode Standard*, version 2.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode2.0.0/), published in 1996 (source: archived PDF copy on Unicode Consortium web site).

The "U+" notation is useful. It gives a way of marking hexadecimal digits as being Unicode code points, instead of octets, or unrestricted 16-bit quantities, or characters in other encodings. It works well in running text. The "U" suggests "Unicode".

My personal recollection from early-1990's software industry discussions about Unicode, is that a convention of "U+" followed by four hexadecimal digits was common during the Unicode 1.0 and Unicode 2.0 era. At the time, Unicode was seen as a 16-bit system. With the advent of Unicode 3.0 and the encoding of characters at code points of U+010000 and above, the convention of "U-" followed by six hexadecimal digits came in to use, specifically to highlight the extra two digits in the number. (Or maybe it was the other way around, a shift from "U-" to "U+".) In my experience, the "U+" convention is now much more common than the "U-" convention, and few people use the difference between "U+" and "U-" to indicate the number of digits.

I wasn't able to find documentation of the shift from "U+" to "U-", though. Archived mailing list messages from the 1990's should have evidence of it, but I can't conveniently point to any.  The *Unicode Standard 2.0* declared, "Unicode character codes have a uniform width of 16 bits." (p. 2-3). It laid down its convention that "an individual Unicode value is expressed as *U+nnnn*, where *nnnn* is a four digit number in hexadecimal notation" (p. 1-5). Surrogate values were allocated, but no character codes were defined above U+FFFF, and there was no mention of UTF-16 or UTF-32. It used "U+" with four digits. [*The Unicode Standard 3.0.0*](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode3.0.0/), published in 2000, defined UTF-16 (p. 46-47) and discussed code points of U+010000 and above. It used "U+" with four digits in some places, and with six digits in other places. The firmest trace I found was in [*The Unicode Standard*, version 6.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/), where a table of BNF syntax notation defines symbols `U+HHHH` and `U-HHHHHHHH` (p. 559).

The "U+" notation is not the only convention for representing Unicode code points or code units.  For instance, the [Python language defines the following string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

- `u'xyz'` to indicate a Unicode string, a sequence of Unicode characters
- `'\uxxxx'` to indicate a string with a unicode character denoted by four hex digits
- `'\Uxxxxxxxx'` to indicate a string with a unicode character denoted by eight hex digits

Comment: Thanks for this explaination @Jim. It is really helpful. I would looking at those linked docs.

Comment: http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2005-m11/0060.html also supports U+HHHH and U-HHHHHHHH.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what version of the Unicode standard you are talking about.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology):

> Older versions of the standard used
>   similar notations, but with slightly
>   different rules. For example, Unicode
>   3.0 used "U-" followed by eight digits, and allowed "U+" to be used
>   only with exactly four digits to
>   indicate a code unit, not a code
>   point.

Comment: That was the helpful reference. But the reason for that change is not mentioned. Was it just a whim of the committee?

Comment: I don't see the "U-" convention in either [The Unicode Standard 3.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode3.0.0/) or [The Unicode Standard 2.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode2.0.0/) as archived on the Unicode Consortium's web site. I think Wikipedia is wrong here.

Comment: It's in the preface (http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode3.0.0/Preface.pdf), but only mentioned briefly.

Answer (score 4):

It is just a convention to show that the value is Unicode. A bit like '0x' or 'h' for hex values (`0xB9` or `B9h`). Why `0xB9` and not `0hB9` (or `&hB9` or `$B9`)? Just because that's how the coin flipped :-)

Comment: They didn't even have to flip a coin: `x` (`/ˈɛks/`) sounds more like `hex` than `h` (`/eɪtʃ/`) does.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi but VB uses `&hB9`, Pascal uses `$B9`, Intel syntax assembly uses `0B9h`

Comment: Thanks phuclv  :-) Yes, the examples were not random :-)